# Oracle Apex List item icons do not show up

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I created a list in Shared Components with two entries, each entry has its own icon. Saved the list, and created a List Region on a page that has a number of List Regions. Specified newly created list as a list for my new region. All works fine, except the list item icons do not hsow up on the page. I checked other, existing lists and region and setup appear the same as the new one but somehow the icons show up just fine on all the old ones.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set in your list region attributes on template options >> display icons >> "For All Items".

[image]

Comment: Tried that and icons appeared but they were different from all the other items. Turned out my list was of type Linked List and all others - Media Lists. Thanks for your suggestion I was able to find the issue